# Verifying image presence on a webpage using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver

I am trying to verify if the image is present on the webpage or not. Can you suggest me the most feasible code. I am giving the necessary details below.

(Here I am referring to the main product image on left top side in green)

Page URL : http://www.marksandspencer.com/ditsy-floral-tunic/p/p60072079

Also I can send the screenshot if you want. Please send me the email id.

Please suggest at the earliest as I am in need of it.

Comment: please add the relevant HTML-code and what you have already tried to solve this problem of yours

Comment: Theoretical question -> theoretical answer: If sourcecode.contains("foo.jpg") -> yolo.

Answer (score 0):

try to check size of found elements by xpath:

```
".//*[@class='s7staticimage']/img"
```

if width is more than 10px -- picture will be shown =)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the ways with which you can verify if the image is present,

1. Checking if the img src contains the file name
2. Checking if the img webelement size if greater than your desired size
3. This one is a little outside the scope of webdriver, you need to get the src attribute from the img webelement, then make a GET request to the src to see if you get a 200 OK.

These above verifications will only help ensure that there is an image present on the page, but you cannot verify if the image you want is being displayed unless you do image comparison.

If you want to do image comparisons then take a look at https://github.com/facebookarchive/huxley

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to verify all images in a webpage - selenium webdriver, TestNG, Java.

public void testAllImages() {

// test webpage - www.yahoo.com

```
    wd.get("https://www.yahoo.com");

  //Find total No of images on page and print In console.
    List<WebElement> total_images = wd.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    System.out.println("Total Number of images found on page = " + total_images.size());

    //for loop to open all images one by one to check response code.
    boolean isValid = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_images.size(); i++) {
     String url = total_images.get(i).getAttribute("src");

     if (url != null) {

      //Call getResponseCode function for each URL to check response code.
      isValid = getResponseCode(url);

      //Print message based on value of isValid which Is returned by getResponseCode function.
      if (isValid) {
       System.out.println("Valid image:" + url);
       System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
       System.out.println();
      } else {
       System.out.println("Broken image ------> " + url);
       System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
       System.out.println();
      }
     } else {    
      //If <a> tag do not contain href attribute and value then print this message
      System.out.println("String null");
      System.out.println("----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------XXXX-----------XXXX----------");
      System.out.println();
      continue;
     }
    }
}
```